# Can't print all values of a multiple rows json string

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do some queries on multiple "rows" json string. What I mean by multiple json string is json string organized like that :

```
[{ 
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Jemmy overy",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:...",
},
{ 
    "id" : 6,
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "data" : {...},
    "link" : "http:...",
}]
```

This is what I've tried to do :

First of all, I have **multiple json files** that I get from HDFS :

```
val df = spark
.read
.format(com.databricks.spark.avro)
.load(namenodeURI)
```

The schema of my json files at this point is organized into two fields :

- header
- body

The column I want to work on is **body** so I used spark-sql to select only this column which is data in JSON format.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Rawdata")
import spark.implicits._
val strBody = spark
 .sql("SELECT body from Rawdata")
 .as[String]
 .collect
 .mkString
```

**Remember that I had multiple json files**, so I have multiple bodies. I don't really know how to get the result from the query, I tried to get it as a String.

My goal from this point is to do some queries with the strBody string. I first convert it to a dataset using an encoder :

```
val ds = spark.createDataset(strBody :: Nil)
val schema = Encoders.product[Root].schema
val ds2 = 
 spark
   .read
   .schema(schema)
   .json(ds).as[Root]
```

Root is a case class which corresponds to the Json schema in the bodies.

When I want to print every content of a specific field of my bodies it only prints the content of the field of the first body returned from my sql query :

```
ds2.map(x => x.someField.someAnotherNestedField).foreach(println(_))
// print only one element, the first element from the strBody variable
```

I tried to add prefix suffix and separator when I get the string from the query to match the syntax of multiple rows json string :

```
val strBody = spark
 .sql("SELECT body from Rawdata")
 .as[String]
 .collect
 .mkString("[",",\n","]")
```

Since I use insert a "\n" character I specify the option multiline when I read the dataset at the end :

```
val ds = spark.createDataset(strBody :: Nil)
val schema = Encoders.product[Root].schema
val ds2 = 
 spark
  .read
  .option("multiline","true")
  .schema(schema)
  .json(ds).as[Root]
```

But then I get a NullPointerException. In fact ds2 doesn't contain any value.

Does someone have an idea on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you post sample that matches with your code example along with `printSchema` on dataframe. Also spark version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to resolve the issue, this is how I proceded :

Instead of creating a string containing the result of my query I returned the dataframe :

```
val bodyDF : DataFrame = spark
 .sql("SELECT body from Rawdata")
```

After that I create a dataset of string from the dataframe :

```
val bodyDS : DataSet[String] = bodyDF.as[String]
```

And finally I create a Dataset of Root :

```
val finalDS : DataSet[Root] = spark
                               .read
                               .json(bodyDS)
                               .as[Root]
```

This kind of statement works perfectly now :

```
finalDS.map(x => x.someField.someAnotherNestedField).foreach(println(_))
```

I hope it will help someone !